# Would there be any way to detect if the app was installed before on Android with current storage policy

Tags: android, date, installation-package

... but with no use of an online database to store some user data or something, because that is basically privacy violation. Before latest storage policy changes it was possible to create a hidden file to store first install date, in case that a user uninstalls the app after the trial period, then install it again, to avoid app purchase.

With current storage policy, still is possible to save the app screenshot, for instance, using MediaStore, by some distinct filename, but in case of an app uninstall/reinstall you can't check if that file exists and file date, even when know the filename.

So, the question is, is it still possible to detect if the app was installed before, but with no use of the internet, and if it is, how?

P.S. Currently suggested answer:

PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);

long firstInstallTime = info.firstInstallTime;

Is 5 years old and it is not valid